# GUI freezing when I use '.get'

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Heres the relevant code:

```
def opencommand():

    number=entry1.get()

    mydata = csv.reader(open('result.csv','rU'))

    card_name = []

    for row in mydata:
        card_name.append(row[9])


    r=0
    while r<number:
        randomnumbers=[]
        counter=0
        while counter<5:

            randomnumbers.append(randint(1,90))
            counter=counter+1

        pack1=[]
        p=0
        while p<5:
            pack1.append(card_name[randomnumbers[p]])
            p=p+1
        print pack1
        r=r+1
```

and....

```
numpac = Label(options_frame,text='Number of Packs')
entry1 = Entry(options_frame)
numpac.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=E)
entry1.grid(row=0,column=1)


openbutton = Button(options_frame, text='Open',command=opencommand)
openbutton.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2)
```

Can anyone tell me why when i include the get part it freezes but if i set it to a fixed number i doesnt?

heres some text as it says theres to much code: vkjberbverihjbvjerhbvjhebvjhervhjberjvhberjhbverhjbvjlerbvjlerbvljerbverjlhbvrejlvhberljvhberljvhberljvbherjlvhberjvlhbevljerbvljerbvlerjhbvelrjbvlerjhbvlejrhbv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `get()` returns a string, not a number. You need to convert it:

```
number = int(entry1.get())
```